# Sequelize ORM connection clean exits

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize and I am trying to use it to create a basic crud api. I am using version ^5.21.2 of the npm package.

When I use node or nodemon to try and run my server locally, nodemon gives me:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes..."
```

I am not sure why this keeps happening but it only happens when I have the 'db.sequelize.sync... ' wrapper function. I cannot figure out what needs to be changed in order for a sustained database connection.

```
db.sequelize.sync(syncOptions).then(function() {
  app.listen(PORT, console.log("==>   Listening on port %s.", PORT));
});
```

I have the development config set up as such:

```
 "development": {
        "username": "root",
        "password": "*Password*",
        "database": "planit",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "dialect": "mysql",
        "operatorsAliases": "false"
      }
```

here is my index for the models

```
"use strict";

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var basename = path.basename(module.filename);
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
var db = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database,config.username,config.password,config);
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this code :

```
db.sequelize.sync(syncOptions).then(function() {
  app.listen(PORT, console.log("==>   Listening on port %s.", PORT));
});
```

Remove `app.listen(PORT, console.log("==>   Listening on port %s.", PORT));`

```
app.listen(PORT, console.log("==>   Listening on port %s.", PORT));
db.sequelize.sync(syncOptions).then(function() {});
```

Comment: Turns out the issue that I was having had more to do with a miscommunication than anything. I had the wrong Database name so Sequelize had no way of connecting to it.